# Differences between Entity Framework SSDL versions

Tags: entity-framework

According to the following URL, there are three versions of the Entity Framework Storage Schema Definition Language:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj652016.aspx

I am developing a tool that should support all of them (including the legacy versions), but unfortunately I was not able find a document that describes the differences between them.

Does anyone know such document or able to describe the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 main versions of EF artifacts (i.e. CSDL, SSDL and MSL). V1 was introduced in the first version of Entity Framework shipped as part of .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. V2 was introduced in EF4 shipped with .NET Framework 4. V3 was introduced in EF5 shipped with .NET Framework 4.5. V3 will also be used by EF6 that will not be shipped as part of .NET Framework but will be a standalone release - here is the project site http://entityframework.codeplex.com. Changes to artifacts (and therefore increasing the versions) are necessary when new features are added to the Entity Framework and it's not possible to use the existing versions to implement these features. I don't have a list of what changed between V1 and V2 but you can find the list of changes between v2 and v3 here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj650889. One way to find what changed is to compare schemas for v1 artifacts with corresponding schemas for v2 artifacts. You can find the schemas in System.Data.Entity.dll - they are embedded resources or on the http://entityframework.codeplex.com by browsing the EF6 code (under src/EntityFramework/Resources/System/Data/{EntityModel|MappingSpecification}) - the schemas have not changed since EF5.

Comment: Wow, a detailed answer directly from the EF team :) Thank you!

Comment: This is the difference between V1 and V2:

<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />

<xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
</code>
These are part of the definition of EntityContainer. Does this add extensibility to the EntityContainer node, for example:

Comment: <EntityContainer extension:ExtensionAttribute="Hello"><extension:ExtensionNode Value="World" /></EntityContainer>

Comment: If this is the only change that from the EF engine standpoint there is no change. The general principle is that artifacts should be extensible and allow elements in a namespace that is different from the artifact namespace (and possibly the empty namespace - don't remember now) and attributes that are not in the empty namespace. Apparently this was missing for the EntityContainer element hence the change.

Comment: My experiments raised another question about an inconsistency: EF5 has two versions: EF5 (for NET45) and EF4.4 (for NET4), it seems that later does not know the V3 schema. Is this really true?

Comment: EF5 consists of two parts - core assemblies living in .NET Framework and EntityFramework.dll. Schemas are handled by the System.Data.Entity.dll that lives in GAC. Since in .NET Framework 4 this assembly handles only v2 EF5 for .NET Framework 4 is using v2. In .NET Framework 4.5 System.Data.Entity.dll handles v3 an therefore EF5 for .NET Framework 4.5 is using v3 (btw this is the reason why enums are not supported on .NET Framework 4). EF6 does not have any EF components in .NET Framework and therefore it is using v3 on both versions of .NET Framework.